# Allow selecting only first day of month in PrimeNG calendar

Tags: angular, datepicker, primeng, primeng-calendar

I have angular application that uses [PrimeNG calendar component](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/calendar).

I need to add a restriction to select only first date of each month.

The component has feature of disabling certain dates by setting `disabledDates` property, or certain days of the week (`disabledDays`). But I haven't found anything that will disable days of the month.

Does anyone have an idea of how to implement this?

Comment: I'd suggest not using a 30 day calendar when you are only giving the user the option to select 1 of those days. Use a year/month selector.

Comment: @Joe I understand. I'll need some other dates in future.

Answer (score 1):

Alright. You could use the `disabledDates` functionality, but clearly it's not going to be feasible to put in every day of the month, so I'd recommend you put in a month's worth of disabled dates, then hook into the `onMonthChange` event to update your disabled dates when the user views another month:

```
<p-calendar [disabledDates]="invalidDates" (onMonthChange)="updateDisabledDates($event)">
```

With something like:

```
public disabledDates: Date[] = [];

function updateDisabledDates(event) {
  const daysInMonth = new Date(event.year, event.month, 0).getDate();
  disabledDates = []
  for (let i = 2; i < daysInMonth; i++) {
    console.log(i)
    disabledDates.push(new Date(event.year, event.month, i));
  }
}
```

Not tested it.

Comment: Thank you. The solution works only sometimes. I have a feeling that the check that verifies the ability of selection is performed in parallel with event handling and this causes the problem, but I'm not sure. I'm debuging and trying out to understand what's going on. Another strange thing is that it works every time while switching from December to January next year and I can't get why.

Comment: Are you sure it's being fired (a console out in the function being called on the right month)? I did worry it only fired when the month changed as the user selected it.

Comment: Yes, it is. Although I didn't use `console.log`. I used brake point in debugger - every time I changed month using a button it did entered the code with correct month.

Comment: Only other way I can think of to do it is maybe disable click events, and style to look disabled, in the css of the day class (except the first element) using something like `pointer-events: none;`